# recalcitrant imaginary in Matlab

Tags: matlab, built-in

Cris - Your suggestion fixed problem with numeric or symbolic calculations. THX
However, it has also led to a problem which I do not understand:

```
syms k
K2 = k^2;
K5 = 2*k^2;
K7 = K2/K5
```

works fine 
    % ans: K7 = 1/2

```
K9=acos(K7)
```

works fine 
    ans: K9 = pi/3

however, attempting conversion on function fails with ERROR

```
K11 = acosd(K7)   
% Undefined function 'acosd' for input arguments of type 'sym'.  
%using either built-in function  

rad2deg(K9)

% Error using rad2deg (line 13)
% Input must be single or double.
```

BUT conversion of result works fine!

```
rad2deg(pi/3)
% ans: 60.0000
```

Comment: ans: Q=t*conj(t) should be ans: Q=k*conj(k).
nb- I am writing a function that uses dot(u,v). It works for numeric values, but the referenced issue prevents it from using symbols only.

Comment: Marsh: if you want to fix or improve your post, you can [edit] it. There is also a link at the bottom left of the question text, just below the tags.

Comment: Also, please clarify your question, I think you are using symbolic math here?

Comment: Note that `dot(u,v) == sum(conj(u).*v)`. If you want this dot product to return `k^2`, you might want to do `sum(u.*v)` instead of `dot(u,v)`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What is `k`?